# Django {% for loop - showing 1 out of 3 values

Tags: python, django

I added for loop to my html, after I added more data to the Queryset. For some reason it's showing 1 out of 3 values I passed. - I could print them, it's just not showing up on the html.

The result page - client_name (in blue), missing product_name + waiting_time (in red)
[image]

Any ideas?  thank you

**models.py**

```
class Orders(models.Model):
created_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
client_id = models.IntegerField()
client_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
delivery_city = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
delivery_address = models.CharField(max_length=50, blank=True, null=True)
product_id = models.IntegerField()
sold_by = models.CharField(max_length=20)
sale_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
units_to_buy = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
order_cost = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100000, blank=True, null=True)
payment_method = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
payment_channel = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
invoice = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
delivery_cost = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100000, blank=True, null=True)
delivery_type = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
delivery_status = models.CharField(max_length=20, default='ממתין למשלוח')
delivery_person_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
modified_date = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.client_name + ' - (' + self.sold_by + ')')

class Clients(models.Model):
first_name = models.CharField(max_length=20)
last_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
client_type = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
company_name = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
address = models.CharField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
city = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
additional_phone_number = models.CharField(max_length=10, blank=True, null=True)
email = models.EmailField(max_length=30, blank=True, null=True)
card_type = models.CharField(max_length=15, blank=True, null=True)
four_digits = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
added = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.first_name)

class Products(models.Model):
product_name = models.CharField(max_length=50, verbose_name=u'שם המוצר')
supplier_name = models.CharField(max_length=20, blank=True, null=True)
purchase_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100000, blank=True, null=True)
purchase_price_before_fees = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100000, blank=True, null=True)
final_price = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100000, blank=True, null=True)
final_price_before_fees = models.DecimalField(decimal_places=2, max_digits=100000, blank=True, null=True)
inventory_in = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
inventory_out = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
inventory_total = models.IntegerField(blank=True, null=True)
notes = models.TextField(blank=True, null=True)
created = models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)

def __str__(self):
    return '{}'.format(self.product_name)
```

**URLs.py**

```
...
path('orders/', views.orders_filter_view, name='orders'),
...
```

**Views.py**

```
def orders_filter_view(request):
   qs = models.Orders.objects.all()
...
for order in qs:
    client = models.Clients.objects.get(pk=order.client_id)
    client_name = client.first_name
    qs.client_name = client_name      <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    product = models.Products.objects.get(pk=order.product_id)
    product_name = product.product_name
    qs.product_name = product_name    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    tz_info = order.created_date.tzinfo
    qs.waiting_time = order.created_date - datetime.datetime.now(tz_info)     <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<

total_matches = qs.count()

context = {
    'orders': qs,     <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
    'view': 'הזמנות',
    'total_matches': total_matches,
    'titles': orders_titles
}

return render(request, 'adolim/orders.html', context)
```

**Orders.html**

```
{% for order in orders %}
                    <tr>
                        <td class="center">{{ order.client_name }}</td>    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                        <td class="center">{{ order.product_name }}</td>    <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
                        ...
                        <td class="center">{{ order.delivery_person_name }}</td>
                        {% if order.delivery_status == 'סופק' %}
                            <td class="center green-text">{{ order.delivery_status }}</td>
                        {% else %}
                            <td class="center">{{ order.delivery_status }}</td>
                        {% endif %}
                        <td class="center yellow-text">{{ order.waiting_time }}</td>   <<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<
```

The result page - client_name (in blue), missing product_name + waiting_time (in red)
[image]

Comment: it raised by you assign the related values to orders but not the items of orders.

Answer (score 0):

One thing you are doing wrong is you run query in a for loop which is a big problem instead I suggest you to create a query with joining tables, one way to do it is using `select_related` or another that I like is using `values`: main difference is `select_related` will return you objects with all the fields while `values` will return an array of dictionaries with specified fields.
More info regarding `select_related` https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/ref/models/querysets/#select-related

```py
# I am not sure how your Models looks like but I assume it is One-to-Many Clients-Orders

def orders_filter_view(request):
   # client, product in quotes is the foreign key field name
   qs = models.Orders.objects.select_related('client', 'product').all()
...
    # I am not sure what are you trying to do with dates
    # But now you can easily access any data from foreign key objects without hitting DB again
    for order in qs:
        print(order.client.first_name)
        print(order.product.product_name)
        tz_info = order.created_date.tzinfo
        qs.waiting_time = order.created_date - datetime.datetime.now(tz_info)
```

Comment: With each order I have the product and client ids, I'm trying to add to the final context details from Clients and Products DB: 
I tried `for order in qs:
        client = models.Clients.objects.select_related('first_name', 'product_name', 'created_date').all()
 
        client_name = client.first_name`

- I'm getting >>> `django.core.exceptions.FieldError: Non-relational field given in select_related: 'first_name'. Choices are: (none)`

- I also tried: `client = models.Clients.objects.select_related('first_name').all().get(pk=order.client_id)`
It didn't work.

Comment: in select related you should specify the **foreign key** not the field from another table

Comment: If you can add the models codes it will be easier to help you!

Comment: This is my models.py (linked at the end, include db for orders, clients, products) shoot me with any suggestions, and begginer mistakes :)  - thank you
https://docs.google.com/document/d/1PSmB8rf7x3HmXH-dry94e45ZEg2krimpVKKG4hzIBog/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: can you please edit your post and add just a few lines of your models not the whole file, thanks

Comment: I'm sorry, I didn't think about it - added

Comment: in you models  `class Orders` you have `client_id = models.IntegerField()` and `product_id = models.IntegerField()` which ideally should be **ForeignKey** `product_id = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE)` and `client_id = models.IntegerField(Clients,  on_delete=models.CASCADE)`

Comment: you need to specify 'related_name' to your foreign keys `product_id = models.ForeignKey(Products, on_delete=models.CASCADE, related_name="order_related_name")` change *order_related_name* for both to be different and unique